# How to update json in array if exist if not exist add

Tags: javascript, json

I need to update json (whitelistype and timestamp), if exist in array. If not exist only add. I provide example of json. Whitelist is:

```
 {Url: "apple.com", WhiteListType: 1, timestamp: 921421321321}
 {Url: "google.com", WhiteListType: 3, timestamp: 721421321321}
 {Url: "telegraf.rs", WhiteListType: 3, timestamp: 521421321321}
```

i have to case. If add and if remove. I will provide code if add:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Whitelist.length; i++) { 
        if ( Whitelist[i].WhiteListType === 3 && Whitelist[i].Url == Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain ) {
            console.log("free")
            // Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain this is only domain on current site which is in tab
            // Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain is our Url in json
            // example of Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain is "apple.com"
            let req3 = {
                Url: Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain,
                WhiteListType: 0,
                timestamp: Date.now()
            }
                Whitelist.unshift(req3);
                console.log("Added white list" , Whitelist) 
                // example Whitelist json is {Url: "apple.com", WhiteListType: 1, timestamp: 921421321321}
                Whitelist2.unshift(Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain)
            return  webSocketClient.SendMessage("newWhiteList%" + JSON.stringify(Whitelist)); 

        }else if (Whitelist[i].WhiteListType === 1 && Whitelist[i].Url === Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain) {
            console.log("Jedan")
            let req3 = {
                Url: Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain,
                WhiteListType: 2,
                timestamp: Date.now()
            }
                Whitelist.unshift(req3); 
                console.log("Added white list" , Whitelist) 
                Whitelist2.unshift(Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain)
                return  webSocketClient.SendMessage("newWhiteList%" + JSON.stringify(Whitelist)); 
        } else   {
            console.log("two situation")
            let req5 = {
                Url: Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain,
                WhiteListType: 2,
                timestamp: Date.now()
            }
                Whitelist.unshift(req5); 
                console.log("Added white list" , Whitelist) 
                Whitelist2.unshift(Preventer[data.WindowId].CurrentDomain)
                console.log("@" ,Whitelist2 )
                return  webSocketClient.SendMessage("newWhiteList%" + JSON.stringify(Whitelist)); 
        } 
    }
}
```

My question. How if Url exist in json only change-update WhiteListType and timestamp, not add new json.?

Comment: that's not JSON, it's 3 javascript objects

Comment: @bravo 
Whitelist: [{{Url: "apple.com", WhiteListType: 1, timestamp: 921421321321}
 {Url: "google.com", WhiteListType: 3, timestamp: 721421321321}
 {Url: "telegraf.rs", WhiteListType: 3, timestamp: 521421321321}]

Comment: that's not JSON either

Comment: Ok how to update js objects?

Comment: `Whitelist[2].WhiteListType = 4` would change the WhiteListType property of the third object in Whitelist to have the value 4 ... does that help?

Comment: No i can't 
I have only 3 WhiteListType-a 
I need check if exist url update WhiteListType
If not exist add new

Comment: that was an *example*

Comment: Ok yes how do it?
I want only update

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < Whitelist.length; i++) { Whitelist[i].WhiteListType = 4; }` would update them all to 4 - seriously, I have no idea what you want to update, since your code doesn't update anything, it unshifts a new object to `Whitelist` inside a for loop that iterates the `Whitelist` - there's no updating going on, it's adding objects to the beginning of the array, meaning your loop will miss double process entries in the array

Answer (score 0):

- Go through the elements of the original array using forEach.
- If an element matches the required Url and WhiteListType, then update
  it and flag that the element already existed.
- After you go through all the elements, if the flag says that it
  didn't exist, add it to the array.

Here is an example:

```js
let originalArray = [{
    Url: "apple.com",
    WhiteListType: 1,
    timestamp: 921421321321
  },
  {
    Url: "google.com",
    WhiteListType: 3,
    timestamp: 721421321321
  },
  {
    Url: "telegraf.rs",
    WhiteListType: 3,
    timestamp: 521421321321
  }
]

const newObject1 = {
  Url: "google.com",
  WhiteListType: 3,
  timestamp: 999999
}

const newObject2 = {
  Url: "yahoo.com",
  WhiteListType: 2,
  timestamp: 999999
}

const resultNode = document.getElementById("result")

function action(newObject) {
  let objectAlreadyExisted = false

  let result = originalArray.map(element => {
    let newElement = { ...element }

    if (newElement.Url === newObject.Url && newElement.WhiteListType === newObject.WhiteListType) {
      objectAlreadyExisted = true
      newElement.timestamp = newObject.timestamp
    }
    return newElement
  })

  if (!objectAlreadyExisted) {
    result.push(newObject)
  }

  resultNode.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result)

}

function reset() {
  resultNode.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(originalArray)
}

document.onload = reset()
```

```html
<button onclick="action(newObject1)">action for newObject1</button>
<button onclick="action(newObject2)">action for newObject2</button>
<button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Ok how to update existing object ?!
if exist Url just update same and replace with old...no add new
if no exist add new
that is all